# Generating a 2D list from nested For Loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, 2d, nested-loops

So, I have a python project for class where we are simulating a 1-dimensional random walk experiment. SO the first part of the problem consisted of us creating a program that would run a For loop 1000 times and would raise/lower the "position" of our initial value by 1. It also saved the position and time values in order to plot as well.

The program for this:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = 0
n = 1000

pos = []
time = []
for i in range(0,1000):
    a = np.random.randint(low,high)

    if a == 0:
        x -= 1
    else:
        x += 1

    pos.append(x)
    time.append(i)

plt.plot(time, pos)
```

The next task is to take this program and run a for loop where we measure 5 different 'trajectories' (basically, we want to produce 5 different plots at once of random walk simulations)

How the question was specifically worded: *"Excellent! Although it would be great to plot a set of these at the same time. Next, put your loop code in an additional loop where a trajectory counter (say, trj) goes from 0 to 4, and store your trajectories in a 2D list. Then, plot all five trajectories below."*

Here is my attempt at a solution:

```
trj = [[] for i in range(5)]


x = 0
n = 1000


for j in range(5):
    pos = []
    time = []
    trj[j] = [time, pos]

    for r in range(0,1000):
        a = np.random.randint(low,high)

        if a == 0:
            x -= 1
        else:
            x += 1

        pos.append(x)
        time.append(r)

plt.plot(trj[1])
```

I keep getting an "out of range" error. All HELP would be appreciated as I truly don't understand 2d lists conceptually (I sort of understand that they contain lists in rows AND columns)

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib's `plot` function takes 2 arguments; in your first example you pass it `time` and `pos` - however in the second example you are passing it a list (`[time, pos]`), which is only a single argument, hence the error

You need to expand this list out to 2 arguments - one way to do this is to use `*args` to expand the list out into a number of arguments to the function:

```
plt.plot(*trj[1])
```

Or if you don't like the `*args` format, the easier-to-follow option:

```
plt.plot(trj[1][0], trj[1][1])
```